# Как сделать функция скрыть нулевой баланс на PHP

Tags: php, mysql

не могу разобраться как сделать так

Есть список балансов, мне нужно реализовать через input checkbox по которому будет скрываться балансы с нулевым значением а так же что бы сохранялся результат после перезагрузки страницы, в теории сохранять результат можно в localstorage. Значение баланса хранится в базе данный (MYSQL).

Не могу разобраться как правильно написать условие.

Буду признателен вашей помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$balances = [100, 0, 50, 0, 75];
$filteredBalances = array_filter($balances, function($balance) {
    return $balance > 0;
});
```

Состояние чекбокса можно хранить с помощью cookies и использовать его для фильтрации балансов на сервере

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['hideZeroBalances']) && $_COOKIE['hideZeroBalances'] == 'true') {
    $filteredBalances = array_filter($balances, function($balance) {
        return $balance > 0;
    });
} else {
    $filteredBalances = $balances;
}
```